# Conflicts with C# EF while migrating

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've just started with EF and I created my models and I'm trying to make a relationship where a user would have multiple devices, I've tried multiple examples but nothing seems to work.

classes:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created_at { get; set; }

    public  ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}

public class Device
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name  { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Gateway { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created_at { get; set; }

    public int User_id { get; set; }
    public User User;

}
```

These are the classes, as I read in the documentation I figured that I'd have to code this on my DbContext:

```
HasMany(t => t.Devices)
            .WithRequired(t => t.User)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

but I still got this error:

```
The expression 't => t.User' is not a valid property expression. The expression should represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'.
```

Comment: you have wrong for User Property without get or set, you should write it like this: `public User User{get;set}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user is currently a field, not a property. Change it to this to make it a property:

```
public User User { get; set; }
```

Comment: That's correct, I also had to make it virtual so the EF wouldn't make it as a Field and I could configure it on my own, thanks.